# Принудительный вызов метода супер класса при переопределении метода в классе наследнике

Tags: java, полиморфизм

Есть класс в котором есть метод который я переопределяю в наследнике.

```
public abstract class RandomClass {
    public void test(){};   
}
```

И в случае если наследник переопределит  метод `test()` - он обязательно должен вызвать супер метод, так:

```
@Override
public void test() {
    super.test();
}
```

В Android  я такое делал с помощью аннотации  над методом супер класса `@CallSuper`.

**Вопрос:** как можно провернуть подобный трюк в чистой Java?

Comment: Имхо, на *vanilla Java* - это никак не сделать

Comment: @andreycha да, я идею понял, но это просто добавление еще одного метода для подклассов - это может решить мою проблему, но меня все таки интересовал другой подход, как в Android SDK.

Comment: @Barmaley вас понял, было бы конечно удобно!

Comment: Я потому ссылку эту и прицепил, что в чистой Джаве так не сделать.

Comment: @andreycha я так понимаю - это единственная возможность решить данную задачу, вопрос можно закрывать?

Comment: напишите свой обработчик аннотаций.

Comment: Для меня аннотации - неизведанная тема, но написать свою - идея хорошая.

Comment: не аннотацию, а обработчик.